# Attempting a fresh install of windows server 2016, stuck in a boot cycle

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, bios, windows-server-2016

I've been trying to install Windows server 2016 on this server for a while now, the issue I have is that when the USB boot disk is plugged into the server, it goes into a boot cycle where it POST beeps, displays the motherboard screen, and then screen goes black, POST again and repeat. I can't get it to go into BIOS or anything else while the USB is plugged in. As soon as I unplug the USB it stops the cycle and I can navigate BIOS settings. I do not think it is the USB that is bad here because I've been able to successfully install Windows server 2016 on a different machine with the same boot disk. I don't reckon that the hardware is bad either, the machine was running fine with linux mint before I wiped the hard drive and tried installing windows. Here's a few things I've tried:

Popping the CMOS battery

Getting into the boot menu, then plugging in the USB, selecting a boot option and then telling it to restart. I tried this with every option it presented me from the boot menu (HDD, CD-ROM, USB-ZIP External card etc.) and I will also note that no additional options popped up upon plugging in the USB.

I know it recognizes hard drives at least so my next idea was to make a boot disk directly onto a hard drive. This did not work because the hard drive seemed to disappear from my system after creating a partition, formatting and attempting to make it bootable. This is also kind of an issue because the drive I used to try and do that is no longer showing up on my computer (not even in disk manager). I've tried restarting, plugging unplugging my drive dock, turning it off/on but the disk wont show up.

I don't know what else to try at this point so if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd try another flash drive even though this one worked on another device. Sometimes the simplest explanation is the best.

Comment: I was finally able to go out and get another USB today, and I tried it with the new USB and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your flash drive is not working correctly. Even though it was working on another device you should try another flash drive.

(Based on the OP's comments this in fact was the solution.)

Comment: Please mark this as the answer so others know it speed the problem for you. Thanks.